# TKinter install settings : "module 're' has no attribute 'compile'" on import

Tags: python-3, tkinter

If I run a "intro to TKinter" program in Thonny, it runs. From the command line or in Mu it gives this:

( Pi3 b, Buster, fresh apt update - install... )

```
..$ python3 code/tkinter_x.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/tkinter_x.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    _magic_re = re.compile(r'([\\{}])')
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

so Thonny ( which says python 3.7.3 ) is picking up something that is different from what the command line gets.
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - self induced library pollution.  Only excuse for having a file named re.py is I downloaded some example code.  Didn't change their name.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo,  thanks for the polite nudge, unfortunately, no tick mark.  - I may have gotten myself into a weird state where the system "almost" recognizes me as poster.  I don't see how to flag a moderator to cure this,  I'm debating just deleting the whole series.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have different accounts with and without spaces. You must accept it with the same account you made the question. I have flagged this answer to a moderator.

Comment: This is the way to go https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts Please note that moderators cannot do anything about this issue you'll have to contact the community manager team.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting update:  if I "feed" the script to python, it works.

:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tkinter
> > >       from tkinter import*
> > >
> > > ### >>> from tkinter import ttk
> > >
> > > ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
> > >
> > > ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=E)
> > >       ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
> > >       ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
> > >       for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
> > >       ... 
> > >       feet_entry.focus()
> > >       root.bind('', calculate)
> > >       '1987255912calculate'
> > >
> > > root.mainloop()

That runs.  So how am I holding my mouth wrong?

Thanks    dave